Starting a foreground service automatically after phone restarts
I have a app created in ReactNative. From ReactNative side I have created a foreground service  using'rn-foreground-service' package. On some action I am starting the foreground service. I can see a notification of service being started.
What I want to do: When user restarts the device, the service should starts automatically. Without user opening the app.
Below is what I have tried so far. When I restart the device, the service does not starts automatically. After few minutes, Android OS gives a dialog with message - "app could not load" and 2 buttons for "App Info" & "force close".
Please let me know what is wrong in below code.
registering in index.js
ReactNativeForegroundService.register(); 
App.js
import ReactNativeForegroundService from '@supersami/rn-foreground-service';

  useEffect(() => {
    let subscription;
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      const { BootBroadcastReceiver } = NativeModules;
      const bootEventEmitter = new NativeEventEmitter(BootBroadcastReceiver);
      subscription = bootEventEmitter.addListener('startService', () => {
         startForegroundService();
      });
    }
    return () => {
      subscription && subscription.remove();
    };
  }, []);

const startService = () => {
        ReactNativeForegroundService.start({
          id: 2,
          title: 'My Foreground Service',
          icon: 'ic_notification',
          color: '#000000',
          message: 'Service is running in the foreground',
        });
}


on android native side,
BootModule.java file
package com.myapp;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.modules.core.DeviceEventManagerModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableMap;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.util.Log;

public class BootModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
    private static final String MODULE_NAME = "BootModule";
    private static ReactApplicationContext reactContext;

    BootModule(ReactApplicationContext context) {
        super(context);
        reactContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "BootBroadcastReceiver";
    }

    // @ReactMethod
    private void sendEvent(String eventName, @Nullable WritableMap params) {
        reactContext
                .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
                .emit(eventName, params);
    }
}


BootPackage.java file
package com.myapp;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class BootPackage implements ReactPackage {

    @Override
    public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @Override
    public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(
        ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        List<NativeModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();

        modules.add(new BootModule(reactContext));

        return modules;
    }

}


BootBroadcastReceiver.java file
package com.myapp;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import com.facebook.react.HeadlessJsTaskService;

public class BootBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String MODULE_NAME = "BootBroadcastReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MyHeadlessTaskService.class);
            context.startService(serviceIntent);
            HeadlessJsTaskService.acquireWakeLockNow(context);
        }
    }
}


The package is also added in MainApplication - getApplication method
packages.add(new BootPackage()); 
MyHeadlessTaskService.java file
package com.myapp;
import android.content.Intent;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import com.facebook.react.jstasks.HeadlessJsTaskConfig;
import com.facebook.react.HeadlessJsTaskService;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MyHeadlessTaskService extends HeadlessJsTaskService {
    @Override
    protected @Nullable HeadlessJsTaskConfig getTaskConfig(Intent intent) {
        return new HeadlessJsTaskConfig(
            "StartForegroundService",
            null,
            1000,
            true
        );
    }
}


Also added services in AndroidManifest.xml
    <receiver
        android:name=".BootBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".MyHeadlessTaskService" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"/>


